# Windows Mobile 6.5 modern GUI development

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-mobile

How to approach a modern GUI development in Windows Mobile 6.5. I can see in .NET CF 2.0/3.5 only legacy common controls, no alpha blended controls, no fading etc. Comparing to Android or Symbian, Windows Mobile 6.5 look-a-like of applications is very elderly. 
Is there support for WPF in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Thanks and Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF is not supported.  Silverlight is not supported in current phones but will be supported with Windows Phone 7.  XNA will be supported on Windows Phone 7.

For the current phones on the market you really have to abandon the idea that you're going to get a decent UI by simply dragging controls out of the toolbox.  That simply is not going to happen.  You can still create compelling UI, but you have to do custom/manual drawing of your controls.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of WPF development for WM.

But there is Silverlight 4 and (theoretically) Windows Phone 7... So if you want to develop for Windows platform you'd probably target Silverlight technology, not WPF. And Windows Phone 7, not WM 6.5

Comment: Exactly, Windows Phone 7 will be an OS based on Silverlight. As to if it will be able to compete again Android and iPhone, we will have to leave that to the marketing department of Microsoft.